# Redux provider in index.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The redux is implemented and working, but I don't know where I need to leave the provider, because if it stays where it is now only one of the elements will be rendered "Router our Provider".

```
        import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
        import store from './store';
        import Idlist from './components/Idlist';
        
        import Signup from './Pages/Signup/Signup';
        import MainScreen from './Pages/Home/MainScreen';
        
        
        const routing = (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Idlist />
          </Provider>,
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Signup} />
              <Route path="/MainScreen" component={MainScreen} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        )
        
        ReactDOM.render(
          routing,
          document.getElementById('root')
        );
        
        reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: If your routes access the redux store, you should wrap everything in `routing` with the provider

Comment: As your code currently stands, you should get an error because there's no top-level component in `routing`. If you want to keep it as it, wrap the components in `routing` in a `React.Fagment`